# Homotopic, Same homotopy type, homotopy equivalent (Are they synonyms?)

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, definition

Just to check my understanding: Are the terms

- Homotopic
- Same homotopy type
- Homotopy equivalent

  exactly the same thing?

From the texts I read, "homotopic" is often used to describe maps, but I have seen it being used to describe two spaces too, e.g. "$X$ is homotopic to $Y$".

Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, the adjective "homotopic" should only apply to maps, and for spaces we should reserve the term "homotopy equivalent". "Same homotopy type" and "homotopy equivalent' are synonyms.

Comment: There are 613 hits on google for the exact phrase "homotopic spaces" and 2,900 hits for the phrase "homotopy equivalent spaces". That should give you an idea of which is more 'proper' (though it's only a factor 5 difference).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you could say that homotopic is a slightly less specific notion. We say that two maps $f,g:X\to Y$ are homotopic if there exists a so-called *homotopy* $F:X\times I\to Y$ so that $F(x,0)=f(x)$ and $F(x,1)=g(x)$. We usually denote this $f\simeq g$.

We can extend this notion to topological spaces $X,Y$ by saying that $X\simeq Y$ ($X$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y$) if there exist maps $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ so that $f\circ g\simeq Id_Y$ and $g\circ f\simeq Id_X$. One might also say that $X$ and $Y$ are homotopic (as spaces). This is not usually a source of confusion. Finally, homotopy type usually describes the same thing. That is, spaces with the same homotopy type are homotopy equivalent. For instance, $\mathbf{D}^n$ (the unit disk in $\mathbf{R}^n$) has the homotopy type of a point, i.e. $\mathbf{D}^n\simeq *$.

Note: Maps are assumed to be continuous maps of topological spaces.